# Xcode 11 tableview crashes on launch

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, ios13

Launching an app that uses a tableview, simulators crash on launch, with:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Attempted to call -cellForRowAtIndexPath: on the table view while it was in the process of updating its visible cells, which is not allowed.
```

The very same code worked in iOS 12 / Xcode 10.2.

Commenting out the highlighted function call below solved the crash:

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    updateRowHeight(indexPath: indexPath) // CRASH IS BECAUSE OF CALLING THIS HERE
    return myTableView.frame.height / CGFloat(CellsDataEnum.allCases.count)
}


func updateRowHeight(indexPath: IndexPath) { // WHICH CALLS THIS
     myTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.textLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: myTableView.frame.height / 10)
}
```

Instead, I now set the font in `cellForRowAt`:

```swift
cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: myTableView.frame.height / 10)
```

Why did the first version work in iOS 12, but crash in iOS 13?

Comment: Asking about betas is fine. But when asking a question about an error, you need to show relevant code so people can attempt to help you find the issue. Also show which line of code is causing the error.

Comment: Note that many times "working" code breaks in iOS updates because the "working" code was never actually the correct way to do something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to be calling `updateRowHeight` from `heightForRowAt`. In fact, that whole `updateRowHeight` method should be deleted. Set the font in `cellForRowAt`.

And given that your `heightForRowAt` is returning the same value for all rows, remove that method too. It's very inefficient. Simply set the `rowHeight` property of the table view once to the desired height.

These changes should work on all iOS versions and be far more efficient as well.

iOS 13 is probably having issues because you are trying to access a cell while the table view is being updated. It may have worked in prior version but it was never a good idea to access `cellForRowAt` from `heightForRowAt`.

Comment: Gotcha. So setting the height in `viewDidLoad` with `myTableView.rowHeight = myTableView.frame.height / amountOfRows` is a good way? Or is there an official, cleaner way? Thanks 

Comment: `viewDidLoad` might be too soon since the table view's height may not be fully set yet. I'd consider putting that in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

Comment: Right! Thanks again.

Comment: viewDidLayoutSubviews this method is Called many times right ? that's why ?

Answer (score 2):

(Apple Via Feedback Assistant)

> - This exception is new in iOS 13 and occurs if you attempt to ask the table view to return a cell while the table view is in the middle of updating its cells.
> - You can learn more about this on the Developer Forums here: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/117537#364166

Answer (score 0):

Very similar problem in my case, solved by avoiding this line:

```
 table.numberOfRows(inSection: cells.count)
```

This attempt to ask the table view to return cell data in the middle of updating its cells causes the crash. The table works fine after deleting the line.